# Distinct select and max in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I've the following table:

```
id | user_id | name | value
----------------------------
1  |       1 | so   | 1
2  |       1 | os   | 2
3  |       2 | so   | 3
4  |       2 | os   | 4
5  |       2 | os   | 7
```

How can I select rows of distinct *users* with *name* == "os" and **max**(*value*) where values IN *list* using sqlalchemy?

**additional,** ***probably useless*** **, info**: I'm using sqlalchemy with pyramid

This is similar to what I've attempted:

```
ResVar = DBSession.query(tableModel.id, tableModel.user_id, tableModel.name, tableModel.value, func.max(tableModel.value)).filter(tableModel.value.in_(list(checkList))).filter(tableModel.name == "so").group_by(tableModel.user_id).all()
```

And this is similar to my model:

```
class tableModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'table'
    id = Column(Integer,primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(100))
    value = Column(String(200))
    user_id = Column(Integer,ForeignKey('user.id'))
    user = relationship("user",foreign_keys=[user_id])

    def __init__(self, user_id,name,value):
        self.user_id = user_id
        self.name = name
        self.value = value
```

Expected result:

```
1 |    1 | so  | 1
3 |    2 | so  | 3
```

Comment: Can you please attach the source code of your model class and code what you have attempted this far?

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa I've added the Model and query. Need anything more?

Comment: Could you also add example result rows based on example table data.

Answer (score 0):

Because SQLite doesn't support `DISTINCT ON`, we have to use the `GROUP BY user_id`:

```
T = tableModel
q = session.query(T.id, T.user_id, T.name, func.max(T.value)) \ 
           .filter(T.name=='so') \
           .filter(T.value.in_([1, 2, 3, 4])) \
           .group_by(T.user_id)
```

Resulting in following rows:

```
(1, 1, u'so', u'1')
(3, 2, u'so', u'3')
```